# What are :horizontal and :vertical pseudo selectors for?

Tags: css, visual-studio, css-selectors

I was writing some CSS in Visual Studio, and while writing a pseudo selector the code tooltip suggested `:horizontal`, so I noticed that there's a pseudo `:horizontal` and `:vertical`.

*Visual Studio 2013 - 12.0.21005.1*

[image]

**What is this selector for, and when do I use it?**

It does not appear on [**MDN Pseudo-Classes Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) standards selectors...

Comment: I'm curious about this. Have never heard about them either.

Comment: Probably something that visual studio implemented

Comment: @Huangism I'm actually thinking it could be it. Maybe Web Essentials.

Comment: It's not definitely not regular css, I never heard of it

Comment: So what is the actual CSS code that Visual Studio generates from that?

Comment: My VS 2013 intellisense doesn't come up with them. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a WebKit-only creation

> :horizontal – The horizontal pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar
>   pieces that have a horizontal orientation.
>
> :vertical – The vertical pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces
>   that have a vertical orientation.

I found reference to these pseudo classes [here](http://davidwalsh.name/custom-scrollbars) and [here](https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/).

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22:horizontal%22+%22:vertical%22+pseudo+class it's number 5 on my results page ;)

Answer (score 6):

Is for custom scrollbar in webkit:

#### Visit this [Article](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

- [Here is webkit-documentation](https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)
- [And here you can play with scrollbars Check It!](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)

---

`:horizontal` – The horizontal pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a horizontal orientation.

`:vertical` – The vertical pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a vertical orientation.

---

`:decrement` – The decrement pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not the button or track piece will decrement the view’s position when used (e.g., up on a vertical scrollbar, left on a horizontal scrollbar).

`:increment` – The increment pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not a button or track piece will increment the view’s position when used (e.g., down on a vertical scrollbar, right on a horizontal scrollbar).

`:start` – The start pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed before the thumb.

`:end` – The end pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed after the thumb.

`:double-button` – The double-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is part of a pair of buttons that are together at the same end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a pair of buttons.

`:single-button` – The single-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is by itself at the end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a singleton button.

`:no-button` – Applies to track pieces and indicates whether or not the track piece runs to the edge of the scrollbar, i.e., there is no button at that end of the track.

`:corner-present` – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not a scrollbar corner is present.

`:window`-inactive – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not the window containing the scrollbar is currently active. (In recent nightlies, this pseudo-class now applies to ::selection as well. We plan to extend it to work with any content and to propose it as a new standard pseudo-class.)

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is... I'll accept Samuel's answer for it was posted first, but thanks. +1

Comment: peace! timing first! :)

Answer (score 4):

They are selectors used for scrollbars. They are specific for WebKit.